# Terminal port to Windows?

Tags: windows, terminal, port

Is there any terminal port to Windows, where i can also install things on like Fink, and custom scripts?

Answer (score 4):

You may consider [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), which is a GNU environment ported to Windows. I don't think it supports Fink (or more precisely I don't think Fink supports Windows), but I could be wrong.